# Now that we have std::array what uses are left for C-style arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization

`std::array` is vastly superior to the C arrays. And even if I want to interoperate with legacy code, I can just use `std::array::data()`. Is there any reason I would ever want an old-school array?

Comment: Note that `<array>` is a heavy standard library header which can increase compilation time a lot (varies between std lib implementations), whereas a C-style array does not require any includes/imports as it is part of the core language/syntax.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Unless I've missed something (I've not followed the most recent changes in the standard too closely), most of the uses of C style arrays still remain.  `std::array` does allow static initialization, but it still won't count the initializers for you.  And since the only real use of C style arrays before `std::array` was for statically initialized tables
along the lines of:

```
MyStruct const table[] =
{
    { something1, otherthing1 },
    //  ...
};
```

using the usual `begin` and `end` template functions (adopted in
C++11) to iterate over them.  Without ever mentionning the size, which the compiler determines from the number of initializers.

EDIT: Another thing I forgot: string literals are still C style arrays; i.e. with type `char[]`.  I don't think that anyone would exclude using string literals just because we have `std::array`.

Comment: You can write a variadic function template which constructs arrays without you having to specify the length.

Comment: With C++17 Class Template Deduction automatic deduction of the number of initializers is supported. For example, "auto a = std::array{1, 2, 3};"

Comment: Nitpick: the type of string literals is `const char[]`

Comment: Since c++17, you can use std::array a4{3.0, 1.0, 4.0};  // which gives you std::array<double, 3> (source : in the code at end of page : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array )

Answer (score 33):

No. To, uh, put it bluntly. And in 30 characters.

Of course, you need C arrays to implement `std::array`, but that's not really a reason that a user would ever want C arrays. In addition, no, `std::array` is not less performant than a C array, *and* has an option for a bounds-checked access. And finally, it is completely reasonable for any C++ program to depend on the Standard library- that's kind of the point of it being Standard- and if you don't have access to a Standard library, then your compiler is non-conformant and the question is tagged "C++", not "C++ and those not-C++ things that miss out half the specification because they felt it inappropriate.".

Comment: Hm. What if you're writing C++ code that gets called from another language and needs something to be passed as a parameter?

Comment: Freestanding implementations are allowed to leave out almost all of the standard library and still be compliant.  I would have serious doubts about a compiler that couldn't implement `std::array` in a freestanding C++11 implementation, though.

Comment: C++0x Final Draft (Document N3092) § 1.4.7 "Two kinds of implementations are defined: hosted and freestanding. For a hosted implementation, this International Standard defines the set of available libraries. A freestanding implementation is one in which execution may take place without the benefit of an operating system, and has an implementation-defined set of libraries that includes certain language-support libraries" .. The STL is not included as a "language-support" library in a freestanding compiler

Answer (score 25):

Seems like using multi-dimensional arrays is easier with C arrays than `std::array`. For instance,

```
char c_arr[5][6][7];
```

as opposed to

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<char, 7>, 6>, 5> cpp_arr;
```

Also due to the automatic decay property of C arrays, `c_arr[i]` in the above example will decay to a pointer and you just need to pass the remaining dimensions as two more parameters. My point is it `c_arr` is not expensive to copy. However, `cpp_arr[i]` will be very costly to copy.

Comment: However, you could pass a multidimensional `array` to a function without loosing dimensions. And if you pass it to a function template, then that function could deduce both the dimension and the size of each dimension, or just one of them two. This might be interesting for scientific template libraries that principally work on arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: a simple `template <typename T, int M, int N> using array2d = std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>;` should solve any of those issues.

Comment: also if have atomic in the mix :)

Comment: Your example `c_arr` is _very_ expensive to copy! You have to provide the code to do so yourself. The pointer it will decay to is a closer equivalent to a reference than a copy and you can use `std::array` to pass a reference if that is what you want.

Comment: @MilesRout *technically*, shouldn't that be `std::size_t` instead of `int`? sorry for nitpicking, but this would make it universal.

Comment: @robbie0630 Yeah you can make it `size_t` if you want, although I can't imagine there are many scenarios where arrays with more than 4 billion rows or columns are necessary.

Comment: @MilesRout, int can be 16 bits on some architecture. And yes you can have an array of more than 32768 elements. size_t is generally 32 bits on the same architecture and it's unsigned.

Answer (score 15):

As Sumant said, multi-dimensional arrays are a lot easier to use with built in C-arrays than with `std::array`.

When nested, `std::array` can become very hard to read and unnecessarily verbose.

For example:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> arr1;
```

compared to

```
char c_arr[3][3];
```

Also, note that `begin()`, `end()` and `size()` all return meaningless values when you nest `std::array`.

For these reasons I've created my own fixed size multidimensional array containers, `array_2d` and `array_3d`. They are analogous to `std::array` but for multidimensional arrays of 2 and 3 dimensions. They are safer and have no worse performance than built-in multidimensional arrays. I didn't include a container for multidimensional arrays with dimensions greater than 3 as they are uncommon. In C++0x a variadic template version could be made which supports an arbitrary number of dimensions.

An example of the two-dimensional variant:

```
//Create an array 3 x 5 (Notice the extra pair of braces) 

fsma::array_2d <double, 3, 5> my2darr = {{
    { 32.19, 47.29, 31.99, 19.11, 11.19},
    { 11.29, 22.49, 33.47, 17.29, 5.01 },
    { 41.97, 22.09, 9.76, 22.55, 6.22 }
}};
```

Full documentation is available here:

http://fsma.googlecode.com/files/fsma.html

You can download the library here:

http://fsma.googlecode.com/files/fsma.zip

Comment: Fixed-size C-style arrays are easy, but if you want to vary the dimensions things get complicated.  For example, given `arr[x][y]`, you can't tell whether `arr` is an array of arrays, an array of pointers, a pointer to an array, or a pointer to a pointer; all for implementations are legitimate, depending on your needs.  And probably most real-world use cases for multidimensional arrays require the size to be determined at run time.

Comment: I would love to see that variadic-template-implementation of n-dimensional arrays! Meta-programming at its best!

Comment: @steffen I did make an attempt a few years ago. You can view it here: https://code.google.com/p/fsma/source/browse/trunk/variadic_template_array.hpp. Test case here: https://code.google.com/p/fsma/source/browse/trunk/variadic_template_array_test.cpp. I'm sure it can be done a lot better though.

Answer (score 5):

The C-style arrays that are available in C++ are actually much less versatile than the real C-arrays. The difference is, that in C, array types can have *runtime* sizes. The following is valid C code, but it can neither be expressed with C++ C-style arrays nor with the C++ `array<>` types:

```
void foo(int bar) {
    double tempArray[bar];
    //Do something with the bar elements in tempArray.
}
```

In C++, you would have to allocate the temporary array on the heap:

```
void foo(int bar) {
    double* tempArray = new double[bar];
    //Do something with the bar elements behind tempArray.
    delete[] tempArray;
}
```

This cannot be achieved with `std::array<>`, because `bar` is not known at compile time, it requires the use of either C-style arrays in C++ or of `std::vector<>`.

---

While the first example could relatively easily be expressed in C++ (albeit requiring `new[]` and `delete[]`), the following cannot be achieved in C++ without `std::vector<>`:

```
void smoothImage(int width, int height, int (*pixels)[width]) {
    int (*copy)[width] = malloc(height*sizeof(*copy));
    memcpy(copy, pixels, height*sizeof(*copy));
    for(y = height; y--; ) {
        for(x = width; x--; ) {
            pixels[y][x] = //compute smoothed value based on data around copy[y][x]
        }
    }
    free(copy);
}
```

The point is, that the pointers to the line arrays `int (*)[width]` cannot use a runtime width in C++, which makes any image manipulation code much more complicated in C++ than it is in C. A typical C++ implementation of the image manipulation example would look like this:

```
void smoothImage(int width, int height, int* pixels) {
    int* copy = new int[height*width];
    memcpy(copy, pixels, height*width*sizeof(*copy));
    for(y = height; y--; ) {
        for(x = width; x--; ) {
            pixels[y*width + x] = //compute smoothed value based on data around copy[y*width + x]
        }
    }
    delete[] copy;
}
```

This code does precisely the same calculations as the C code above, but it needs to perform the index computation by hand *wherever the indices are used*. For the 2D case, this is still feasible (even though it comes with a lot of opportunities to get the index calculation wrong). It gets really nasty in the 3D case, though.

I like writing code in C++. But whenever I need to manipulate multidimensional data, I really ask myself whether I should move that part of the code to C.

Comment: It should be noted that at least Clang and GCC support VLA's in C++.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen and also that they are horribly limited in which element types they support.

Comment: Doesn’t C11 make VLA optional? If so then I think your answer is misleading. It would be correct when C99 was the standard but not C11.

Comment: @Zboson C99 is a C standard, and there are compilers that implement its VLA features (`gcc` for instance). C11 has made quite a bit of interesting stuff optional, and I don't think that's because they want to outlaw the feature. I tend to see it as a sign that they wanted to lower the level for writing a fully standard compliant compiler: VLA's are quite a difficult beast to implement, and much code can do without, so it makes sense for a new compiler on some new platform to not have to implement VLA's right away.

Comment: VLAs were added in the c++14 standard but removed quickly. G++ and Clang++ have had VLAs since about 2005 and still do. (Mainly just MSVC that refused to implement them; maybe some freestanding compilers would have issues.) The main beef I have with C++ raw arrays is that 2d arrays won't initialize both row and column size from a list so you need to manually count the length of every item in an initialize list of c-strings .

Answer (score -1):

May be the `std::array` is not slow. But I did some benchmarking using simple store and read from the std::array;
See the below benchmark results (on W8.1, VS2013 Update 4):

```
ARR_SIZE: 100 * 1000
Avrg = Tick / ARR_SIZE;

test_arr_without_init
==>VMem: 5.15Mb
==>PMem: 8.94Mb
==>Tick: 3132
==>Avrg: 0.03132
test_arr_with_init_array_at
==>VMem: 5.16Mb
==>PMem: 8.98Mb
==>Tick: 925
==>Avrg: 0.00925
test_arr_with_array_at
==>VMem: 5.16Mb
==>PMem: 8.97Mb
==>Tick: 769
==>Avrg: 0.00769
test_c_arr_without_init
==>VMem: 5.16Mb
==>PMem: 8.94Mb
==>Tick: 358
==>Avrg: 0.00358
test_c_arr_with_init
==>VMem: 5.16Mb
==>PMem: 8.94Mb
==>Tick: 305
==>Avrg: 0.00305
```

According to the negative marks, the code I used is in the pastebin ([**link**](http://pastebin.com/5UDDtmzy))

The benchmark class code is **[here](http://pastebin.com/LEutYGSU)**;

I don't know a lot about benchmarkings... My code may be flawed

Comment: Benchmark results without benchmark code, or compilation flags? Come on, you can do better.

Comment: FWIW, just that small bit of code already shows the benchmark is severely flawed. A smart enough compiler will just turn the whole thing into `long test_arr_without_init() { return ARR_SIZE; }`

Comment: That was just an example. I thought it was not big deal. I changed the code to return void, used release build in VS 2013, with /O2 /Ot /Gl.

Comment: Removing the return value means the compiler can turn the whole thing into `void test_arr_without_init() {}` now. You really need to jump through hoops to make sure the code you are measuring is the code you want to measure.