# How to initialize a tuple of non-default-constructible not-copyable objects?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++03, boost-tuples

Given some classes with parameterized constructors, such as:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(bool b, int i) { /*...*/ }
private:
    A(const A&) {}
};
class B
{
public:
    B(char c, double d) { /* ... */ }
private:
    B(const B&) {}
};
```

How to properly initialize a tuple of such classes?

```
boost::tuple<A,B> tup( /* ??? */ );
```

Not using copy constructor of A or B, and, if possible, not using move-constructor either. C++03 solution preferred, if possible.

Comment: For your edit, you may look at [why-is-there-no-piecewise-tuple-construction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846634/why-is-there-no-piecewise-tuple-construction)

Comment: If you can make your types movable, you should. There are very few cases where a type should not be movable. (In the standard library, atomics, mutexes, and condition variables are not movable for technical reasons.) If you cannot make your types movable, you might use `std::unique_ptr<A>` as a workaround.

Comment: @Brian: move-constructor is a possible option that I'd prefer to avoid though, in order for my code to be compilable on non C++11 compliant compiler. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: so... `std::tuple` is fine but move constructors are not?

Comment: @Brian: He used `boost-tuples` in his tag.

Comment: @Brian: yes, using boost tuples and vc10 compiler

Comment: If you want a C++03 solution you should indicate that in your question. Same goes for if particular compiler.

Comment: @M.M: sorry, I indeed should have mentioned clearly that a C++03 solution is prefered (not mandatory though) to a C++11 solution.

Comment: @Jarod: thanks for the link, I think I'll a to move to vc14...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just add a piecewise constructor for your types? If so, you can create a horrible macro that unpacks and delegates a tuple:

```
#define CONSTRUCT_FROM_TUPLE(CLS)                      \
    template <class... Ts>                             \
    CLS(std::tuple<Ts...> const& tup)                  \
        : CLS(tup, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{})   \
    { }                                                \
                                                       \
    template <class Tuple, size_t... Is>               \
    CLS(Tuple const& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) \
        : CLS(std::get<Is>(tup)...)                    \
    { }
```

And just add it to your types:

```
struct A {
    A(bool, int ) { }
    A(const A& ) = delete;
    CONSTRUCT_FROM_TUPLE(A)
};

struct B {
    B(char, double ) { }
    B(const B& ) = delete;
    CONSTRUCT_FROM_TUPLE(B)
};
```

And pass in tuples:

```
std::tuple<A, B> tup(
    std::forward_as_tuple(true, 42), 
    std::forward_as_tuple('x', 3.14));
```

---

Pre-C++11, I don't know that this is possible - you don't have delegating constructors at all. You'd have to either:

1. Write your own `tuple`-like class that accepts tuples in its constructor
2. Add tuple constructors to your types that explicitly initialize the same thing as the non-tuple versions did
3. Have a tuple of types that are single-argument constructible, like `boost::tuple<boost::scoped_ptr<A>, boost::scoped_ptr<B>>(new A(...), new B(...))`

(1) is a lot of work, (2) is code duplication and error prone, and (3) involves now having to do allocation all of a sudden.

Comment: FYI: He used [tag:boost-tuples] as a tag, so `std::tuple` is not the intent.

Comment: @Nicol It'd be great if the intent were completely spelled out in the question in one go, rather than incrementally in various comments...

Comment: @Barry: I thought the tags would have clarified this (no C++11 tag, boost-tuple tag), but I was wrong, sorry. Anyway, thanks for all the available solutions you provided, I'll probably go for solution 3 until I move to C++11. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following:

```
tuple<A,B> tup(A(true, 42), B('*', 4.2));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I forgot to mention that copy constructor cannot be used. Question edited. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Note that it would use the move constructor if possible.