# Initialize a tuple of non-copyable and non-movable classes

Tags: c++, stdtuple

Consider class A with the only custom constructor:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(float) {}

private:
    A() = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};
```

And another class B, which contains a tuple of A (let it be the only tuple member for simplicity):

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : ta(0.0f) {} // ta initialization OK

private:
    std::tuple<A> ta;
};
```

Now we can declare an object of B and it works fine:

```
B b;
```

But how to do the same if the constructor of `A` has more than one argument?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(float, int) {}

private:
    A() = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class B
{
public:
//  B() : ta(0.0f, 1) {} // Compilation errors
//  B() : ta({0.0f, 1}) {} // Compilation errors
//  B() : ta{0.0f, 1} {} // Compilation errors
//  B() : ta(A(0.0f, 1)) {} // No constructor to copy or move A

private:
    std::tuple<A> ta;
};

B b;
```

`std::make_tuple`, `std::forward_as_tuple` and others like that don't solve the problem, because default, copy and move constructors of `A` are disabled.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24888173

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::tuple` has few facilities for constructing its members in-situ. The generally expected way to initialize a `tuple` is via copy/move from its component objects.

It does permit implicit conversion of constructor parameters to their respective arguments. But that is only a 1:1 relationship between parameters and `tuple` members. There is no way to have a many-to-one relationship between constructor parameters and `tuple` members.

You *can* allow your type to be implicitly constructible from a `tuple` itself:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(float, int) {}
    A(const std::tuple<float, int> &tpl)
        : A(std::get<0>(tpl), std::get<1>(tpl)) {}

private:
    A() = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};
```

Thus, you can construct a `tuple` like this:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : ta(std::tuple<float, int>(0.0f, 1)) {}

private:
    std::tuple<A> ta;
};
```

If you want to employ deeper metaprogramming, you may yet be able to make a set of constructors that allow your type to be constructed from a `tuple` whose types match any available constructors:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(float, int) {}

    template<typename ...Args>
    A(const std::tuple<Args...> &args) : A(args, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}) {}

private:
    A() = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;

    template<typename ...Args, std::size_t ...Is>
    A(const std::tuple<Args...> &args, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
        : A(std::get<Is>(args)...) {}
};
```