# How viable are the alternatives to C-style arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11, arrays, list-initialization, stdarray

Now that we have `std::array`, `std::vector` and brace initialization, are C-style arrays still needed?

Comment: @AndyProwl could you be more specific: What are the possible use cases?

Comment: @JohnnyW: What do you think `std::array` contains?

Comment: @JesseGood Yes, I know that they are used for the implementation of std::array, but that doesn't mean that non-stdlib developers should use it

Comment: This could be discussed to no end... On one hand, legacy C arrays are necessary for some class implementations. On the other hand, they should not appear in "end-user" code. So, yes and no.

Answer (score 12):

One thing that C-style arrays still hold over `std::array` is *size deduction*. You can do the following with C-style arrays, [but not really with `std::array`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6114067/500104):

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; // no explicit size
```

Now, we also have another candidate for C-style arrays replacement: `std::initializer_list`. Internally, it is backed by some kind of array-like storage, but observe:

```
#include <initializer_list> // needed

// ...
auto list = {1,2,3,4,5}; // no explicit size, and no explicit type!
```

And `decltype(list) == std::initializer_list<int>`. However, currently, you can't query the size or elements of such an `std::initializer_list` at compile-time, as the member-functions aren't marked `constexpr` (yet, fixed in C++14). Also, an even bigger problem: `std::initializer_list` only provides `const`-access to the elements, so you can't mutate them.
But caution: `std::initializer_list`s have *reference semantics* and if they are returned from a function, you'll have a dangling reference to some storage.

In the end, I'd say there's still a place for C-style arrays in some narrow situations and niches, but in the general case, we have better options available now with `std::array` and `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer! so if I understand correctly, when it will be possible to query the size of an `initializer_list` in compile time, even this advantage will go away? I guess you can then design a template function to return a std::array and have the size deducted, right?