# more modern way of looping through C++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c++11

Recently I have found a lot of examples, most of them regards the C++ 98, anyways I have created my simple-array and a loop ([codepad](http://codepad.org/aAdu4Nmo)):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string texts[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
   for( unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(texts); a = a + 1 )
   {
       cout << "value of a: " << texts[a] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value of a: Apple
value of a: Banana
value of a: Orange

Segmentation fault
```

It's working fine, except the segmentation fault at the end.

My question is, does this array/loop through is done a good way? I am using C++ 11 so would like to be sure it fits the standards and couldnt be done a better way?

Comment: Just use `std::array` and its `size()` function.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In C/C++ `sizeof`. always gives the number of bytes in the entire object, and arrays are treated as one object. Note: `sizeof` a pointer--to the first element of an array or to a single object--gives the size of the *pointer*, not the object(s) pointed to. Either way, `sizeof` does *not* give the number of elements in the array (its length). To get the length, you need to divide by the size of each element. eg.,

```
for( unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(texts)/sizeof(texts[0]); a = a + 1 )
```

As for doing it the C++11 way, the best way to do it is probably

```
for(const string &text : texts)
    cout << "value of text: " << text << endl;
```

This lets the compiler figure out how many iterations you need.

as others have pointed out, `std::array` is preferred in C++11 over raw arrays; however, none of the other answers addressed why `sizeof` is failing the way it is, so I still think this is the better answer.

Comment: For added simplicity try `for(auto & text : texts)`

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y or even better: `for(auto &&text: texts)`

Comment: For the first way, won't this only work if all the strings are of the same length?

Comment: @tmath My math should work fine with OP's example because each `string` object is actually a constant size regardless of the length of the encapsulated string. In particular a `string` object is essentially just a struct with a _pointer_ to the data, and a bit of other constant-size metadata.

Comment: Note, this may work for C++, but this is dangerous to use in C. It works in C for statically-declared arrays that are on the stack, but will not work in a function. In a function, the sizeof operator does not know about the whole array, and instead will return the size of the pointer.

Comment: @RamblingMad Can you explain why this is better?

Answer (score 33):

```
string texts[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
for( unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(texts); a = a + 1 )
{
    cout << "value of a: " << texts[a] << endl;
}
```

Nope. Totally a wrong way of iterating through an array. `sizeof(texts)` is not equal to the number of elements in the array!

The modern, C++11 ways would be to:

- use `std::array` if you want an array whose size is known at compile-time; or
- use `std::vector` if its size depends on runtime

Then use range-for when iterating.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 3> texts = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
    // ^ An array of 3 elements with the type std::string

    for(const auto& text : texts) {   // Range-for!
        std::cout << text << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/571099612d40c2e7)

---

You may ask, how is `std::array` better than the ol' C array? The answer is that it has the additional safety and features of other standard library containers, mostly closely resembling `std::vector`. Further, The answer is that it doesn't have the quirks of decaying to pointers and thus losing type information, which, once you lose the original array type, you can't use range-for or `std::begin/end` on it.

Comment: Note: they could still use the range-based loop with their original array.

Comment: I don't like the `std::array` approach since I need to count the elements myself. In the traditional way the compiler creates the array of the right size for me.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y [There's a work-around for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6114067/1619294)

Comment: the only thing WRONG is their sizeof calculation

Answer (score 15):

`sizeof` tells you the size of a thing, not the number of elements in it. A more C++11 way to do what you are doing would be:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, 3> texts { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange" };
    for (auto& text : texts) {
        std::cout << text << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ideone demo: http://ideone.com/6xmSrn

Comment: hey, this is awesome!  but should probably explain what it means and how it works.

Answer (score 4):

you need to understand difference between std::array::size and sizeof() operator. if you want loop to array elements in conventional way then you could use std::array::size. this will return number of elements in array but if you keen to use C++11 then prefer below code

```
for(const string &text : texts)
    cout << "value of text: " << text << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a very short list of elements you would like to handle, you could use the [std::initializer_list](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) introduced in C++11 together with auto:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    for(const auto& ext : { ".slice", ".socket", ".service", ".target" })
        std::cout << "Handling *" << ext << " systemd files" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
    std::array<std::string, 3> text = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
    std::for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), [](std::string &string){ std::cout << string << "\n"; });

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and works with C++ 11 and has no 'raw' looping :)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(texts)` on my system evaluated to 96: the number of bytes required for the array and its string instances.

As mentioned elsewhere, the `sizeof(texts)/sizeof(texts[0])` would give the value of 3 you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Add a stopping value to the array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string texts[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", ""};
   for( unsigned int a = 0; texts[a].length(); a = a + 1 )
   {
       cout << "value of a: " << texts[a] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. texts[a].length() is the length of the word at index a. Not the length of the array.

Comment: @htellez Yes, that’s the point. The loop exits when it encounters a string with a length of zero.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't caught that.

Comment: The code work well thanks it solved my problem too, but how can `string texts[]` work to declaring arrays? why mine didn't? i'm using codeblock minGW 17.12

Comment: Doesn't work if you have empty strings elsewhere in your array...

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view:
It is because the sizeof() operator returns the size
of a type in bytes.
So, Simply we can use size() instead of sizeof(). If
we need or must use sizeof() we have to divide it
with sizeof(dataType):

First way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string texts[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
   for (int a = 0; a < size(texts); a++)
   {
     cout << "value of a: " << texts[a] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Second way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string texts[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
   for (int a=0; a<sizeof(texts)/sizeof(string); a++)
   {
     cout << "value of a: " << texts[a] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
   string texts[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
   for ( unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(texts) / 32; a++ ) // 32 is the size of string data type
   {

       cout << "value of a: " << texts[a] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: 32 is not the size of the string data type everywhere and at all times.

Answer (score -1):

Feels like its illegal but this works:

So basically it is dynamic multidimensional array iteration termination case and it differs a bit from one dimensional solution, last element is -1 and it is stop value for cycle (I am new to C++ but this method me likes)

```cpp
int arr[][3] = {{164, 0, 0}, {124, 0, 0}, {92, 4, 0}, {68, 4, 0}, -1};

for(int i = 0; arr[i][0]!=-1; i++)
{
    cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: except what if -1 is actually a value used?  This is a horrible practice and extremely brittle, also this wont even compile as -1 is not an aaray of size 3.

Comment: @UpAndAdam it compiles, it is dirty solution but works and will never collide with -1 so basically -1 is artificial breakpoint in the array while looping

Comment: so what is at arr[5][0] arr[5][1] and arr[5][2] ?  you are just inserting a {-1,-1,-1} element in to the data and deciding that is a sentinal when you have no knowledge that is a safe sentinel value.  It's not modern C++11 and doesn't apply generally (if using other data or other types of elements, what if type was unsigned or a massive dataset?)  this is nothing more than a brittle hack you admit is dirty and only fits into your contrived variant example. What if negative numbers were in the dataset?  It's not a dynamic multidimensional array either the length is set at compile time.