# auto in for loop causes "begin" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I started learning C++ two days ago and this error I am getting is obscure to me, I am trying to do the following

```
int sumArray(const int arr)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (auto &n : arr) {
    sum += n;
  }
  return sum;
};

int main () 
{
  int numbers[] = {1, 2, 5, 10};
  return sumArray(numbers);
}
```

which is a slight change from an example in "A Tour of C++", the error I am getting is

`cpprepl.cpp: In function ‘int sumArray(int)’:
cpprepl.cpp:4:18: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
   for (auto &n : arr) {
                  ^~~
cpprepl.cpp:4:18: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
cpprepl.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cpprepl.cpp:13:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return sumArray(numbers);
                          ^
cpprepl.cpp:1:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int sumArray(int)’
 int sumArray(const int arr)
     ^~~~~~~~`

If I do

```
int main () {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 5, 10};

  int sum = 0;
  for (auto &n : arr) {
    sum += n;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

everything is fine, so I suspect I am not understanding pointers and how C++ is passing `numbers` to `sumArray`; I've seen multiple questions on similar subjects but I'm still missing how this should be done.

Comment: s/`int sumArray(const int arr)`/`int sumArray(const int arr[4])`

Comment: @user0042 Did that, still getting the first two errors about `begin` and `end`.

Comment: I'd recommend you should use a `std::vector<int>` instead of a raw array.

Comment: I'm not there yet. BTW: even with your edited answer I still get the error.

Comment: You should be. Using the standard C++ library is what's preferred over usage of raw arrays or pointers. The latter stuff is advanced, not vice versa.

Comment: @user0042 A parameter `const int arr[4]` has type `const int *`, not `const int [4]`.

Comment: I can imagine that, I'm not there yet though. I want to understand what I'm doing wrong, not use a better data structure.

Comment: When passing the array as a parameter, it "decays" to a pointer. Pointers cannot be used with that form of for-statement as there is no way to get the length of the array the pointer *might* be pointing to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni It explains the essential problem of your question (besides the silly typo) well though.

Comment: @user0042 What you call silly typo is actually me not understanding C++ yet. It might be explaining the problem, but how is a newbie supposed to know what "array decaying" is?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni _"but how is a newbie supposed to know what "array decaying" is?"_ That's why and how we point them in the right directions. Who ever set up a policy that Stack Overflow needs to be _"newbie friendly"_?

Comment: @Alberto - Pointers and passing array parameters are really difficult parts that C++ has inherited from C. That's why you immediately get the recommendation to use a `std::vector` instead. That is C++'s solution to most of those problems. `std::vector<int>   arr` just works, both as a declaration and as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't support the `foreach`-style loop for this sort of array, since it doesn't have any size information to construct the underlying iteration.  As suggested in the comments, it would be better to just use `std::vector`.

---

If the size information would be available, such as in the case where both the array and `for` are in the same "scope", it *might* work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234898/correct-way-of-loop-through-the-c-arrays) for info.

Comment: I saw it was suggested in the comments but without motivation I can't really just accept is as truth :D, thanks for adding the *why*.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni that's the case I was referring to in the second paragraph. The compiler knows that `arr` has 4 elements because that's how you've defined it. So it knows how to translate the `foreach`-style loop into a regular `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)` loop. In the first case it doesn't have that info inside the `sumArray` function, so it can't do anything. Sure, it _could_ look and see that you're calling it with an array of `4` elements, but that would be very burdersome to do generally for large programs. And impossible if you plan on exporting the function from a binary for later use.

Comment: ah-ha! Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, `const int arr` doesn't make sense since it's just a single `int`, not an array, and `const int *arr` and `const int arr[4]` mean the same thing and declare `arr` as a pointer without information about how many `int`s are pointed to. The error message is just confusing.

To allow keeping track of this *without* using standard library container types, you can pass the array by reference:

```
int sumArray(const int (&arr)[4])
```

To allow arrays of arbitrary length to be passed in, you can make it a function template:

```
template <int N> int sumArray(const int (&arr)[N])
```

Comment: Passing arrays by reference is underused.

Comment: Ok now I understand why I should not use a raw array, it feels like a lot of work and I don't like to introduce a new thing (the function template, whatever that is :D), I can just use a vector. Thanks!