# Unexplained last item in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array:

```
int distances[10] = {10, 11, 14, 12, 11, 14, 9, 7, 10, 10};
```

When I ran this array through this for loop:

`for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
        std::cout << distances[j] << " ";
}`

and printed all of the outputs, this was my output:

```
10, 11, 14, 12, 11, 14, 9, 7, 10, 10, 4196294, 0, -487465136, 30021, 0, 0, 0, 0, -359687355, 26470, 0
```

Why are the last 11 elements so varied in size and not in the rest of the array?

Comment: Hello. Can we see the loop please?

Comment: Looks like you looped 11 times,  not 10!

Comment: `7` is missing from the output.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You didn't include the loop you are actually using and that is probably the problem in your code.

Comment: Your array only contains 10 elements (indexed 0 to 9) but your loop iterates 20 times (0 to 19). Iterating past the end of an array means you are reading undefined memory locations, that's why you get the random numbers.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains 10 elements (indexed 0 to 9)

```
int distances[10] = {10, 11, 14, 12, 11, 14, 9, 7, 10, 10};
                     ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^  ^  ^   ^
                     0   1   2   3   4   5   6  7  8   9
```

but your loop iterates 20 times (0 to 19)

```
int distances[10] = {10, 11, 14, 12, 11, 14, 9, 7, 10, 10}; ?      ?
                     ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^  ^  ^   ^    ^      ^
                     0   1   2   3   4   5   6  7  8   9    10 ... 19
```

Iterating past the end of an array means you are reading undefined memory locations, which is why you get the random numbers - it's data being interpreted as integers.

You can calculate the number elements in the array using

```
sizeof(distances)/sizeof(distances[0])
```

but if you are using C++11 you should be able to use

```
for(int distance : distances)
```

Search for related questions here on stackoverflow, such as the [Correct way of loop through the C++ arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234898/correct-way-of-loop-through-the-c-arrays) and [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)