# A cheap way to create a class that returns string constants to enums and vice versa?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it better to do:

```
class Foo{

std:string option1(MY_ENUM type){
    static const std:string f1 = "a";
    static const std:string f2 = "b";
    static const std:string f3 = "c";
    // ...
    switch (type) {
        case (TYPE_1):{
            return f1;
            break;
        }
        case (TYPE_2):{
            return f2;
            break;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or do this:

```
class Foo {
private:
    const std:string f1 = "a";
    const std:string f2 = "b";
    const std:string f3 = "c";

public:
std:string option1(MY_ENUM type){

    // ...
    switch (type){
        case (TYPE_1):{
            return f1;
            break;
        }
        case (TYPE_2):{
            return f2;
            break;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Likewise I would do something similar to convert the enum to the string.
Is it better to keep the strings as static const within the function, or as private within the class ?
- No one else is going to edit the class but me.
- It doesn't really matter if any other functions inside the class know what the values of the strings are, and since it is const they can't modify it anyway.

Which is cheaper and has less overhead at runtime and during compilation ? Which is a better practice ?

Comment: Just create a table with pairs { enumValue, stringValue }.

Comment: There is no need to `break` after a `return`. That makes the `switch` version probably the tersest you can get.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use `const char*`'s instead of proper `std::string`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheaper would be not to use `std::string` at all since it will likely require run-time initialization and also use a lookup table to translate from enum to string:

```
const char *enumToStr(MY_ENUM type) {
    static const char *const names[] = { "a", "b", "c" };
    if (type < sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]))
        return names[type];
    return nullptr;
}
```

Unfortunately you can't use this kind of trick for a reverse conversion. Also this assumes that your enumerators have contiguous numerical values and you should be careful when adding or reordering your enum's values.

As for "where to put these values" question, it doesn't really matter from the "overhead" point of view as long as this array is static or global. I would suggest putting it into a global variable within an anonymous namespace inside the *.cpp file that defines these conversion functions, so that it can be used for both functions but isn't visible outside of this translation unit:

```
namespace {
    const char *const names[] = ...;
}
```

Comment: Not the best solution. It relies on enum values start from 0 and have no blanks.

Answer (score 3):

The most common implementation in c++ is to setup a map for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

enum MY_ENUM { 
      TYPE_1
    , TYPE_2 = 42 // Mind the gap please!
};

const char* const option1(MY_ENUM type) {
    static std::unordered_map<MY_ENUM, const char* const> enum2StringMap = 
       { { TYPE_1, "a" }
       , { TYPE_2, "b" }
       // ...
       };

    if(enum2StringMap.find(type) == enum2StringMap.end()) {
        // throw exception or do whatever to indicate an error
        return "Invalid enum value";
    }

    return enum2StringMap[type];
}
```

For the *vice versa* option you might need to take the burden to keep a second map, and synchronize it with the 1st one:

```
MY_ENUM option1(const std::string& s) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, MY_ENUM> string2EnumgMap = 
       { { "a" , TYPE_1  }
       , { "b" , TYPE_2  }
       // ...
       };

    if(string2EnumgMap.find(s) == string2EnumgMap.end()) {
        // throw exception or do whatever to indicate an error
    }

    return string2EnumgMap[s];
}
```

---

Another option making the synchonization easier (but may have other drawbacks regarding performance) could be using a [`boost::bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

---

```
int main() {
    std::cout << option1(TYPE_1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << option1(TYPE_2) << std::endl;

    std::cout << option1("a") << std::endl;
    std::cout << option1("b") << std::endl;
}
```

---

Output:

> ```
> a
> b
> 0
> 42
> ```

---

Not as *"cheap"* as [@r3musn0x proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55499831/1413395), but eliminates the concerns mentioned in [@KonstantinL's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499698/a-cheap-way-to-create-a-class-that-returns-string-constants-to-enums-and-vice-ve#comment97706768_55499831).
There will be a little overhead when the maps are initialized at first access, but any foolowing up search might be optimized to be *O(log n)* vs. *O(n)* time complexity.

---

See a working [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cce2ab19d02fdeb1).

Comment: How do you do the reverse way? Linear search?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Was that also in question? Well, I'd probably take the burden to initialize another map (using `std::string` or at least `std::string_view` as key value).

Comment: It's both in the title and the text after the code snippet. Also, one day you have to tell me how to pronounce that nickname - I've settled for "rhasta pie" for some reason.

Comment: For enum-to-string mapping, `unordered_map` would likely be faster.

Comment: @MaxLanghof _"Also, one day you have to tell me how to pronounce that nickname - I've settled for "rhasta pie" for some reason."_ **Rasta Pie** sounds somehow cool, and seems to be appropriate for me ole' pothead :-D. But the pronounciation is _panta rei_ (a as in _fat_). Here's more [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus#Panta_rhei,_%22everything_flows%22)

Comment: @Paul THX, I incorporated this.

Comment: @Max I am answering the _vice versa_ function as well now.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @KonstantinL's approach; I too think you would be best served by avoiding `std::string`s to the extent that you can. But I would also like to avoid maps...

```
class Foo {
public:
enum MY_ENUM { 
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2
};

protected:
    using pair_type = std::pair<MY_ENUM, const char*>;
    // the following will work with C++17:
    // See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6114067/1593077
    // about initializing std::arrays without specifying the length.
    static constexpr const auto names_and_codes = std::array {
        pair_type { TYPE_1, "a" },
        pair_type { TYPE_2, "b" },
    };

public:

static const char* name_of(MY_ENUM t) noexcept
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(names_and_codes.begin(), names_and_codes.end(),
        [&t](const auto& pair) { return pair.first == t; }
    );
    if (iter != names.end()) { return iter->second; }
    return nullptr; // Or handle the not-found case differently
}

static MY_ENUM code_for(const char* name) noexcept
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(names_and_codes.begin(), names_and_codes.end(),
        [&t](const auto& pair) { return std::strcmp(pair.second, name) == 0; }
    );
    if (iter != names.end()) { return iter->first; }
    return MY_ENUM{-1}; // Or handle the not-found case differently
}

// more code for class Foo 
}
```

This uses a static array instead of a map; linear search in contiguous memory is faster than binary search on trees on with heap-allocated nodes - for a limited number of values, which seems to be the case for you. Also - no use of the heap at all here.

Notes:

- This fixed-size-array-backed "map" can be factored out and made generic, in a separate header. It comes in useful sometimes.
- If your array is sorted, you can make one of the searches binary.

Comment: Why avoiding maps in preference of guaranteed _O(n)_ search behavior?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Asymptotics are irrelevant for small sizes... have a look at: https://ideone.com/b3OnH - and that's a pretty large vector vs a map.

Comment: Another [discussion](https://terrainformatica.com/2017/10/15/when-linear-search-is-faster-than-stdmapfind-and-stdunordered_mapfind/) involving unordered maps as well, but up to 10 items.