# Can I add a deduction guide to `std` namespace?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-faq, deduction-guide, template-argument-deduction

Suppose I want to make a new deduction guide making the following possible ?

```
std::string str;
std::basic_string_view sv = str;
```

Would that be an Ok customization ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[[namespace.std]/2.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std#2.4):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares [...] a
>   deduction guide for any standard library class template.

Comment: Will leave the question open to see if anyone has a workaround as well.

Comment: @darune Probably not.  There is no user-defined type involved in the declaration `std::basic_string_view sv = str;`, so I don't think it's customizable.  Maybe define your own `auto sv = view(str);`?

Comment: @darune: Marking an answer as accepted does not "close" the question; people can (and do) still post answers on such questions.