# What are my options for adding deduction guides for stl types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, deduction-guide

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992794/can-i-add-a-deduction-guide-to-std-namespace) post already explains how adding deduction guides in the std namespace is undefined.
Now, what I would really like to do is this:

```
namespace std { // undefined behavior
template <class... U>
array(char const*, U...) -> array<string, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
}
```

So this is what I've tried:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array : std::array<T, N> {};

template <class... U>
array(char const*, U...) -> array<std::string, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;

template <typename T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

And it works

```
auto const arr = array{ "hello", "world" };
// array<std::string, 2ul>
```

My question now is: 
**Q:** Is this my only option for adding deduction guides for stl types? Are there other options?

Comment: I don't think even this is feasible. STL containers don't exactly support inheritance. You can, in theory, derive from them but their better use case is as members or local variables.

Comment: Why does it need to be a deduction guide? A simple function for this specific purpose will do as well. You won't be able to use the `array` type with this additional deduction to create an array of `const char*` pointers. It would be quite surprising to a user if there are special cases like this. For example with string literals as you are showing here, a type `std::string<const char*, 2>` would be perfectly reasonable and on the otherhand the user can specify the array to be an array of strings easily by adding the `s` literal suffix to the string literals.

Comment: Custom `make_array` seems the more reasonable IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this my only option for adding deduction guides for stl types?

Yes - in the sense that what you did was not adding a deduction guide for a type in the standard library, it was adding a deduction guide for your own type (that happens to inherit from a standard library type). You can always add deduction guides to your own types.

> Are there other options?

This doesn't *have* to use CTAD. You could also write a function:

```
auto const arr = make_array("hello", "world");
```

Such that `make_array` gives you an `std::array<T, N>` where `T` is the decayed type of the first element or, if that type is `char const*`, `string` instead.