# Difference between array<int,5> b; and int b[5];

Tags: c++, arrays

```
array<int, 5> b = {12,45,12,4};
int B[5] = { 12, 45, 12, 4 };
for (auto item : b)
{
    cout << item << endl;  // 12,45,12,4, 0
}
cout << endl;
for (auto item : B)
{
    cout << item << endl;  // 12,45,12,4, 0
}
```

What is the difference between `array<int,5> b`; and `int b[5];`?

Comment: I think u should check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111565/now-that-we-have-stdarray-what-uses-are-left-for-c-style-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template class std:;array is defined as a structure. It is an aggregate and has some methods as for example `size()`.
The difference is for example that arrays have no assignment operator. You may not write

```
int b[5] = { 12, 45, 12, 4 };
int a[5];

a = b;
```

while structures have an implicitly defined assignment operator.

```
std::array<int, 5> b = { 12, 45, 12, 4 };
std::array<int, 5> a;

a = b;
```

Also using arrays you may not use initialization lists to assign an array. For example the compiler will issue an error for the following statement

```
int b[5];
b = { 12, 45, 12, 4, 0 };
```

However you can do these manipulations with `std::array` For example

```
std::array<int, 5> b;
b = { 12, 45, 12, 4, 0 };
```