# Allocating static array with new

Tags: c++

No matter what syntax I try, this code is always a compile error:

```
int (*foo)[3] = new ???;
```

I've tried

```
int (*foo)[3] = new (int[3]);
int (*foo)[3] = new (int(*)[3]);
int bar[3];
int (*foo)[3] = new decltype(bar);
```

Comment: *why* are you trying to do this in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111565/now-that-we-have-stdarray-what-uses-are-left-for-c-style-arrays

Comment: Why not `std::vector` or `std::array` as this is C++ and not C?

Comment: Fun. Obviously I'd normally `std::make_unique<std::array<int, 3>>`

Comment: What compiler errors do you get in each case?

Comment: `Cannot convert from int* to int(*)[3]`, `Cannot convert from int(**)[3] to int(*)[3]`, `Cannot convert from int* to int(*)[3]`

Comment: Use an alias to help clean things up: `typedef int myArrType[3];` or `typedef std::array<int, 3> myArrType;` or `using myArrType = int[3];` or `using myArrType = std::array<int, 3>;`. Then you can do `myArrType *foo  = new myArrType; ... delete foo;` or `std::unique_ptr<myArrType> foo(new myArrType);` or `auto foo = std::make_unique<myArrType>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's easy.

```
int (*foo)[3] = new int[1][3];
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Is it possible to make it deletable with `delete` instead of `delete[]`?

Comment: @Artikash Anything allocated with `new` is "deletable". The key here is to figure out how to delete it.

Comment: I am trying `int (*f)[3] = new int[3];` but the `new int[3]` decays from array to pointer. I don't thing using `delete` is possible - even if you can allocate memory, you would allocate an array of 3 integers and store the pointer to it in `foo`. That's still an array.

Comment: You can allocate the memory for pointer itself `int (**foo)[3] = new (int(*)[3]);` that would free with delete.

Comment: My guts tells me `int (*foo)[3] = 
    reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3]>(new int[3])` should be ok, because it's the same as `int mem[3]; int (*foo)[3] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3]>(mem);` and `&mem` and `mem` have the same value (different type)...